# Hostsファイルに自身のIPと任意のホスト名を記載し、エクスプローラのアドレスバーに記載したホスト名にてアクセスした際にアクセスが出来ない

Tags: network, ipアドレス, hosts

Hostsファイルに自身のIPと任意のホスト名を記載し、エクスプローラのアドレスバーに記載したホスト名にてアクセスした際に資格情報が表示され、許可されているユーザIDとパスワードを入力してもアクセスが出来ません。

■目標
①Hostsファイルに記載したホスト名にて自身にアクセスを行いたいです。
②アクセスが出来ないのであれば、何故出来ないのか理由を知りたいと考えています。

■環境
Windows 10 Home
バージョン1903

■手順
①コマンドプロンプトにてipconfigコマンドを使用し、IPｖ4 アドレスを取得
②Hostsファイルにて手順④にて取得したIpv4アドレス　任意のホスト名を入力し保存する。
③エクスプローラを開き、アドレスバーに「\手順⑤にて入力したホスト名」を入力する。
④アクセスが出来ず資格情報が表示されることを確認する。

■補足
①エクスプローラにて以下を入力した場合はアクセスが可能です。（Hostsファイルで設定したホスト名のみアクセスできない）
　・\localhost
　・\127.0.0.1
　・\[手順④にて取得したIpv4アドレス］
②コマンドプロンプトにてping 「手順⑤にて入力したホスト名」を入力すると
Hostsファイルで設定されているIPアドレスから応答があることを確認できる。

■これまでに試した事
・Administratorでログインをして上記手順を行う
→資格情報が表示されアクセスできない

・作成したローカルユーザでログインをして上記手順を行う
→資格情報が表示されアクセスできない

・表示された資格情報にてAdministratorの情報を入力する
→ユーザまたはパスワードが正しくない　と表示される

・表示された資格情報にて作成したローカルユーザの情報を入力する
→ユーザまたはパスワードが正しくない　と表示される

・資格情報マネージャにてあらかじめ資格情報を記載した状態でアクセス
→資格情報が表示されアクセスできない

・共有フォルダを作成し、共有フォルダにアクセスしてみる
①Dドライブ直下にフォルダを作成する
②共有フォルダのプロパティから「Everyone」をアクセス許可する。
③「\手順⑤にて入力したホスト名」\「作成した共有フォルダ名」を入力する。
④資格情報が表示されアクセスできないことを確認する
⑤「\手順⑤にて入力したホスト名」\D$\「作成した共有フォルダ名」を入力する。
⑥資格情報が表示されアクセスできないことを確認する

知識不足な点があり、大変恐縮ではございますが、
原因・解決策が分かる方がおりましたらご教授頂きたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: hostsファイルは使っていませんが同様の現象を確認したのですが、状況は大きく違えども https://superuser.com/q/933755 が似たような現象のようで……

Answer (score 1):

以下のレジストリキーを作成して再起動してください。

キー：`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
名前：`OptionalNames`
種類：`REG_SZ`
値：別名（例：`mypc`）

再起動後、コンピュータ名（NetBIOS名）が追加され、共有フォルダへのアクセスが可能になります。
次のコマンドで確認できます。

```
> nbtstat -n

Ethernet LAN:
ノード IP アドレス: [10.0.2.15] スコープ ID: []

                NetBIOS ローカル ネーム テーブル

       名前               種類         状態
    ---------------------------------------------
    WIN10          <00>  一意          登録済  <- もともとのコンピュータ名
    MYDOMAIN       <00>  グループ        登録済  <- ワークグループ or ドメイン
    WIN10          <20>  一意          登録済  <- もともとのコンピュータ名（共有フォルダ用エントリ）
    MYPC           <20>  一意          登録済  <- 追加したコンピュータ名（共有フォルダ用エントリ）
```